# Socket and thread in C

Tags: c, sockets

I have the following code:

The file is `principal.c` that it has the function main and others methods.

In main():

```
connectAll(&NUM_THREADS);
printf("TOTAL clients that to connect %d\n",NUM_THREADS);

pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_attr_t attr;

/* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
paramThread params[NUM_THREADS];

  for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
  {

    printf("What's IP [%s] to connected now? %d\n",regIPConnected[t].ip,regIPConnected[t].idSocket);

    params[t].idSocket=regIPConnected[t].idSocket;
    params[t].idThread=t;

    rc = pthread_create(&(thread[t]), &attr,conectaThread, &(params[t]));
    if (rc) 
    {
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
    } 
  }//END FOR

  /* Free attribute and wait for the other threads */
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) 
  {
    rc = pthread_join(thread[t], &status);
    if (rc<0) {
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
    }
    printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status of %ld\n",t,(long)status);
  }//END FOR

  printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *conectaThread (void *arg){

  paramThread* params = (paramThread*) &arg; 

  int idSocket=params->idSocket;
  long tid=params->idThread;

  printf("Thread %ld starting...\n",tid);
  printf ("ID SOCKET THREAD %d\n",idSocket);
  while (1) /* Run forever */
  {

    int state=readSocket(idSocket,"status\n");

...
}
```

The structure of paramThread is:

```
typedef struct
{
  int idSocket;
  long idThread;
  void (*pf)(int, long);
} paramThread;
```

And another file, called socket.c

```
int openSocketInet (char *servIP,unsigned short servPort)
{
  int optval,statusSocket=0;
  socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval);

  /* Create the socket, using TCP */

  socketClient = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  printf("OK/NOK socket %d",socketClient);
  if (socketClient<0)
  {
    switch (errno) 
    {

      /*differents cases of errno*/
      default:  
    perror("socket()");
    statusSocket= -1;
    }//END SWITCH
  }//END IF


    /* Check the status for the keepalive option */
  if(getsockopt(socketClient, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, &optlen) < 0 && statusSocket==0) {
    statusSocket=checkGET_SETSockOpt(socketClient,1);
    printf("Error getsockopt() is %d\n",statusSocket);
  }//END IF

  printf("SO_KEEPALIVE is %s\n", (optval ? "ON" : "OFF"));

  int fl = fcntl(socketClient, F_GETFL);
  fcntl(socketClient, F_SETFL, fl | O_NONBLOCK);

  /* Set the option active */
  optval = 1; //-->TRUE
  optlen = sizeof(optval);

  if(setsockopt(socketClient, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen) < 0 && statusSocket==0) {
    statusSocket=checkGET_SETSockOpt(socketClient,0);
    printf("Error setsockopt() is %d\n",statusSocket);
  }//END IF

  printf("SO_KEEPALIVE set on socket\n");

  /* Check the status again */
  if(getsockopt(socketClient, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, &optlen) < 0 && statusSocket==0) {
    statusSocket=checkGET_SETSockOpt(socketClient,1);
    printf("Error getsockopt() is %d\n",statusSocket);
  }//END IF

  printf("SO_KEEPALIVE is %s\n", (optval ? "ON" : "OFF"));


  if (connect(socketClient, (struct sockaddr *)&addressServer, sizeof(addressServer)) < 0 && statusSocket==0)
  {
    switch (errno) 
    {
      /*diffents cases of errno to connect()*/
      default:  
    perror("connect()");
    statusSocket= -1;
    }//END SWITCH
   }//END IF

  /* Construct the server address structure */
  bzero(&addressServer, sizeof(addressServer)); /* Hay que poner todo a ceros */

  addressServer.sin_family = AF_INET;           /* Internet address family */
  addressServer.sin_port = htons(servPort); /* puerto en formato de red */

  /* dirección IP en formato de red */
  int errInetAton=inet_aton(servIP, &addressServer.sin_addr);
  if (errInetAton<0 && statusSocket==0) 
  { 
    printf("Fail the conversion of IP\n",servIP);
    perror("inet_aton() Motive");
    statusSocket= -1;
  }//END IF


  printf("The IP %s to connect with sock %d\n",servIP,socketClient);

  //To return identify a socket or  fail
  if (statusSocket<0)
    return statusSocket;
  else
    return socketClient;

}
```

When I running the result is:

```
socket(): Success --> to sock 3
SO_KEEPALIVE is OFF
SO_KEEPALIVE set on socket
SO_KEEPALIVE is ON
The IP x.x.x.x to connect with sock 3
socket(): Illegal seek --> to sock 4
SO_KEEPALIVE is OFF
SO_KEEPALIVE set on socket
SO_KEEPALIVE is ON
The IP y.y.y.y to connect with sock 4
```

I wish I could connect to different ip having the same socket

---

Thanks, the problem is another:

```
What's IP [x.x.x.x] to connected now? 3
What's IP [y.y.y.y] to connected now? 4
What's IP [z.z.z.z] to connected now? 5


Out for
Thread 5 starting...
ID SOCKET THREAD 5
Method READ! Send to socket id [5] and data is '[status]'
STATUS THREAD 0
Thread 5 starting...
ID SOCKET THREAD 5
Method READ! Send to socket id [5] and data is '[status]'
Thread 5 starting...
ID SOCKET THREAD 5
Method READ! Send to socket id [5] and data is '[status]'
STATUS THREAD 0
Info: (-3.35 dB)
Method WRITE! Send to socket id [5] and data is '[outlevel 0:50
]'
El conector estÃ¡ marcado como no bloqueante y la operaciÃ³n solicitada lo bloquearÃ­a.
Method WRITE! Error send() is 0
Level modify of Vol 50%
Info: (-24.13 dB)
Level modify of Vol 50%
Info: (-52.60 dB)
Method WRITE! Send to socket id [5] and data is '[outlevel 0:50
]'
El conector estÃ¡ marcado como no bloqueante y la operaciÃ³n solicitada lo bloquearÃ­a.
Method WRITE! Error send() is 0
Level modify of Vol 50%
Method READ! Send to socket id [5] and data is '[status]'
hi0!
send(): No route to host
Method READ! Error send() is -1
STATUS THREAD -1
Method READ! Send to socket id [5] and data is '[status]'
#
```

But the socket number is incorrect should be 3 or 4, the next code :

In main()

```
...
for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
  {

    printf("What's IP [%s] to connected now? %d\n",regIPConnected[t].ip,regIPConnected[t].idSocket);
```

idSocket=regIPConnected[t].idSocket;

```
    rc = pthread_create(&(thread[t]), &attr,conectaThread,&idSocket);
    if (rc) 
    {
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
    } 
  }//END FOR

  printf("Out for\n\n!");

  /* Free attribute and wait for the other threads */
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) 
  {
    rc = pthread_join(thread[t], &status);
    if (rc<0) {
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
    }
    printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status of %ld\n",t,(long)status);
  }//END FOR

  printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
```

}

The other code is same. Why not to get the first socket "3" and get the finish socket 5?? and why to finish the threads?

Thanks

Comment: too long, didn't read...

Comment: *I don't know, how do I do what create a socket and connect the differents ip that I declared in a file of configuration of IP's* - Would it be possible to rephrase that statement into English?

Comment: Sorry, I don't expres very well

Comment: Sorry it is a bummer - try *Sorry, I did not express that very well*. But on a practical note can you reduce the question to a manageable size?

Comment: "Illegal seek" is `ESPIPE`, which should not be set by a call to `socket()`. I expect it is set by the `printf()` between the call to `socket()` and the call to `perror()`. So to me it looks this `printf()` set `errno` to `ESPIPE`. And as also `"OK/NOK socket..."` is missing: Could is be you `close()`ed `stdout` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out this line

```
printf("OK/NOK socket %d",socketClient);
```

And see if you get further.

For details please see my comment on the OP.

Comment: Thanks, I see it and I think that problem can be to incorrect parameters to pass

Comment: @user1248467 you are welcome. Btw: I would not mind if you'd upvote and accepted my answer though ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you declaring socketClient anywhere in the socket initialization function. If it's a global, it should be guarded by a mutex or some other mechanism serializing access to it.

In general,

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

should not fail under normal conditions. Either you have exceeded your system fd/socket quota, or more likely, lacking proper access synchronization to the socket.

Also, as mentioned, too much code, and too little context.